# Serializing a container of RSS feeds?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, rss, feed

I am working on a project for an RSS Client.  Right now I'm retrieving a feed using `SyndicationFeed` and an `XmlReader` and adding it to a list:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(
    XmlReader.Create("SOME URL TO A FEED"));
List<SyndicationFeed> feeds = new List<SyndicationFeed>();
feeds.Add(feed);
```

`SyndicationFeed` and most of its properties are not serializable.  I need to be able to save the feeds and their respective items when my program is closed.  I have a database solution working with Entity Framework but I would like to get away from this.  So my next thought was to simply serialize the container with all the feeds but that's no go.  Should I write serializabl class that mimics the `SyndicationFeed` and its properties and do a sort of boxing and unboxing or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SyndicationFeed` class has a [`SaveAsAtom10` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.saveasatom10.aspx) and a [`SaveAsRss20` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.saveasrss20.aspx), both of which take a [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) instance which you can use anything as the underlying store for.

Personally, I'd go with the `SaveAsAtom10` method, as I believe Atom is the richer format.

That said, you can easily persist this into a larger single document by creating a root element and child element in your own namespace, and then having the contents of each feed as the child, like so:

```
<feeds xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MyFeedContainer">
    <feed>
        <!-- Atom feed -->
    </feed>
    <feed>
        <!-- Rss feed -->
    </feed>
    <!-- And so on.. -->   
</feeds>
```

I'd use an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) instances to handle creating the container above, as namespace management is *much* easier when using those classes.  Additionally, the `XElement` class exposes a [`CreateWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createwriter.aspx) and a [`CreateReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createreader.aspx), which will expose `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader` instances respectively, which you can then pass to your `SaveAsAtom`/`SaveAsRss20` methods.

However, I'd impress upon you to store each of the items separately; depending on how many feeds you have, creating one massive super document might be too much of a drain on resources, depending on your needs.  Single document instances persisted in individual entities which you can access independently would probably be much more efficient to process.

You can still use the `SaveAsAtom10` and a `SaveAsRss20` methods to serialize the feeds.

Comment: Thanks.  So just keep each feed in its own document on disk?

Comment: @Pete: That's how I'd do it.  I'd name it in such a way that you know how to retrieve the specific feed (if necessary) or you can just enumerate through the files in the directory if you need to process them as a whole.